# Java + React-Native: Bridging java camera module

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-camera

I'm new to android development and I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial on how to create a custom native camera component with Java and then accessing that module from the react-native code. Are there any resources available for creating a bridge between an Android Camera component and react native code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `react-native-camera-kit` if you want to handle the preview. But you can't analyze the real-time image.

Comment: I need to access the camera feed as well. Also, do you know if this runs on the UI thread? Previously my camera was running on the react-native thread but the processing was taking too long.

Comment: Yes its on UI. But doesn't provide frame data and not built in cameraX. You have to create your own custom UI View via bridge